# SonarQube 4.4 and SCMActivity plugin

Tags: sonarqube

We recently installed SCMActivity plugin in our 3.6.1 installation and it worked without a hitch. Now that we are prepping to move to 4.4, installing the same plugin (version 1.8) does not yield same results - svn blame is not working. I am not sure why.
Our setup is all Centos, SVN 1.8, Sonar 4.4, SCMActivity plugin 1.8.

Comment: What do you get in the logs? You can run the analysis with "-X" option to get debug information and therefore have more details on what's going on.

Comment: With debug on, I can see authors listed in the output:
[DEBUG] [06:07:30.257] Author of line 1: smith (2012-03-29)
[DEBUG] [06:07:30.257] Author of line 1: smith (2012-03-29)
[DEBUG] [06:07:30.257] Author of line 1: jones (2012-03-29)
[DEBUG] [06:07:30.257] Author of line 1: brown (2012-03-29)
[DEBUG] [06:07:30.257] Author of line 2: jones (2012-03-29)


When I go to Sonar project they are not listed line by line on the left of the display.

Comment: Have you activated the SCM decoration on the Component Viewer ? => http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/SCM+Information+tab

Comment: Yes - still no change.

Comment: Oh wait - got it! This is different behavior than what we saw in Sonar 3.6. Thank you for talking me through it!

Comment: You're welcome! I will turn my comment into an answer so that you can accept it and therefore help other people.

Answer (score 0):

Since SonarQube 4.5, you need to turn on SCM decoration on the Component Viewer to be able to see SCM information. See the [documentation on the SCM Tab](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/SCM+Information+tab).